# Swedish tax agency skatteverket.se reports an higher annual income than actual. How to verify?

Tags: income-tax, income-tax-refund, sweden

I'm expat no longer living in Sweden but need refund form skatteverket.se. The income reported seems higher than actual received. Actual received is reverse calculated from salary and other benefits credited to account as employer has not provided any document.

Comment: you should check with your employer and see how they reported the income and why they did it the way they did. you should also have received a w2 equivalent that explains the breakdown. remember that retirement, employer match and some other things like bonuses can count towards income that go beyond the actual wage received. at least in the US that's the way it works, I can't image they are that much more different in how they handle things as well. If they have not provided you this document, you should request it and they are obliged to provide it.

Comment: what's a "w2 equivalent"? some US thing?

Comment: A w2 is a US income and tax withholding statement received by employees from their employer at the end of a tax year. I believe the Swedish equivalent is called a KU10.

Comment: I see. It seems to be similar to a KU10 indeed

Answer (score 1):

Every month, your employer is supposed to not only give you your salary but also pay your taxes to Skatteverket. This is part of your salary. So if your salary is 20,000 SEK you'll get say 14,000 SEK paid out to your bank account and 6,000 SEK is paid to Skatteverket.

You're supposed to be informed about how much is paid to Skatteverket from your salary of course. At the end of the year, a *kontrolluppgift* is provided by your employer to Skatteverket, you're supposed to be provided a copy from your employer.

However, on Skatteverket.se you should be able to see how much tax has been paid for you. If you add that to your calculated income, does it not add up? If not, you'll have to ask your employer.

Comment: This seems the most likely explanation for discrepancy, and agreed that OP should contact employer to confirm and get written documentation.